# Talend - System env variables not reflecting without restart

Tags: etl, talend

I'm using system environment variables to parameterise jobs in talend, But every time I change any value, without restarting talend I'm not able to get the changes reflected. Is there any workaround? I don't want to use Context groups or Implicit Context load. I'm using Talend Open Studio free edition. Is this any different in Enterprise version?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with Talend is handling environment variables. Talend is reading the environment variables at startup and stores them. There is [a good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434065/how-to-retrieve-the-modified-value-of-an-environment-variable-which-is-modified) which explains this behavior in more detail regarding Java (Talend is build on Java).

There are also some tricks listed how to get the variables depending on your OS.